# Instantiating ReportDocument on Windows 7 machine crashes app

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

When I try to instantiate a ReportDocument my app crashes - even when wrapped in a try/catch block. This only happens on Windows 7 machines (it might also happen on Vista - I haven't tested it there). Machines running XP don't have a problem at all.

```
try
{
    ReportDocument doc = new ReportDocument(); // This cause the app to crash
}
catch (Exception ex)
{        
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); // This never executes
}
```

The specific dll reference is CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine version 11.5.3700.0

Any ideas?

Comment: That's the thing - there is no error message. Just the "This application has encountered an error must close" message. If you investigate, all you can discover is that the error came from my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had this identical problem.  We installed Crystal Reports XI R2 Service Pack 4 Full Build on the client Windows 7 machine, and it solved the issue.  It is my understanding that this "full" Service Pack is a complete install of Crystal Reports XI R2.  I read in a message board that CRXIR2 Service Pack 6 was necessary for Windows 7 compatibility, but SP4 was sufficient.

The Service Pack can be downloaded from the SAP website, but they may need to register a login.  The website is not intuitive.

Interestingly, we had a Virtual PC instance of Windows 7 running and we could not repeat the error in the virtual environment.  It was only when we built a physical Windows 7 box that we saw the error in-house.

Comment: I forgot all about this question (and switched jobs to boot). If I remember correctly, we fixed it by installing the service pack too.