# An unhandled win32 exception occured in w3wp.exe - Windows 8 IIS 8 Classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, winapi, iis, crystal-reports, w3wp

I have a website made in classic ASP that I'm trying to migrate from a windows xp development machine to a windows 8 development machine and in production from a Windows Server 2003 machine to Server 2012. We use Crystal Reports Report Application Server 9 to generate reports.

In windows 8 I installed IIS 8 and configured the .NET 2 classic application pool to use 32 bit applications and set the identity to Network Service. I installed CR9 RAS and the 64 bit runtime. When I go to print a report on the website I get this error on the first line that creates a CR object:

```
An unhandled win32 exception occured in w3wp.exe
```

I ran DebugDiag and was able to get a crash dump as follows:

```
In w3wp__.NET v2.0 Classic__PID__2220__Date__10_03_2013__Time_12_59_55PM__954__Second_Chance_Exception_C000041D.dmp the module C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll has caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to write to memory location 0x03f77de0 on thread 35

Thread 29 - System ID 2736
Entry point   cachemanager!DllUnregisterServer+accd 
Create time   9/26/2013 12:30:24 PM 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 0:0:0.0 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 0:0:0.0 

Full Call Stack

Function     Arg 1     Arg 2     Arg 3     Arg 4   Source 
cachemanager!DllUnregisterServer+78c5     029e8a63     000e00be     00000081     00000000    
user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+100     029e8a63     029e8a63     00000000     000e00be    
user32!DispatchClientMessage+15d     012a2170     00000000     00000081     00000000    
user32!__fnINLPCREATESTRUCT+8d     03fdf6f4     00000000     03fdfc10     770e2bf0    
ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcher+2e     00000000     0000c083     0000c083     00000000    
user32!VerNtUserCreateWindowEx+238     00000000     00000000     80000000     00000000    
user32!CreateWindowInternal+26b     0000c083     00000000     80000000     00000000    
user32!CreateWindowExW+37     00000000     0000c083     00000000     80000000    
cachemanager!DllUnregisterServer+7a3d     00000000     03fdfba8     00000000     80000000    
cachemanager!DllUnregisterServer+75d9     00000000     05335d98     05335d98     00000000    
cachemanager!DllUnregisterServer+6e94     05335688     00000000     00000000     05335d98    
cachemanager!DllUnregisterServer+ad2c     05335d98     03fdfc70     770fbf39     05335d98    
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+e     05335d98     8eb1ec43     00000000     00000000    
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+72     029ebeab     05335d98     ffffffff     77171df7    
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b     029ebeab     05335d98     00000000     00000000    


Exception Information
In w3wp__.NET v2.0 Classic__PID__356__Date__09_26_2013__Time_12_30_24PM__637__Second_Chance_Exception_C000041D.dmp the module C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll has caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to write to memory location 0x04443000 on thread 29

Module Information 
Image Name: C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll   Symbol Type:  PDB 
Base address: 0x00905a4d   Time Stamp:  Thu Sep 20 00:10:05 2012  
Checksum: 0x00000000   Comments:   
COM DLL: False   Company Name:  Microsoft Corporation 
ISAPIExtension: False   File Description:  Multi-User Windows USER API Client DLL 
ISAPIFilter: False   File Version:  6.2.9200.16420 (win8_gdr.120919-1813) 
Managed DLL: False   Internal Name:  user32 
VB DLL: False   Legal Copyright:  © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 
Loaded Image Name:  user32.dll   Legal Trademarks:   
Mapped Image Name:     Original filename:  user32 
Module name:  user32   Private Build:   
Single Threaded:  False   Product Name:  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System 
Module Size:  1.09 MBytes   Product Version:  6.2.9200.16420 
Symbol File Name:  c:\symcache\wuser32.pdb\81836B9A16A64DBBB5209E254A61DD072\wuser32.pdb   Special Build:  &
```

It seems that possibly network service doesn't have access to something so I went to the directory CR installs in, the whole C drive, the windows temp folder, and my website folder and gave them all full control from network service with no change.

I tried uninstalling crystal reports and hitting that page to see a different error but I still got the same crash so I'm not sure if it is an actual install issue or something more serious in terms of how I configured IIS or classic ASP for IIS 8.

I am trying sysinternals process monitor now and I'm seeing some buffer overflows but since I don't know how to use the program I'm not sure if it is with this dlls or even from iis.

How can I further debug or solve this issue?

**UPDATE:**

IO ran sysinternals process monitor and I was able to see when my asp page is hit I get a buffer overflow. After this occurs, when the Crystal Reports DLLs are called it says **FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS**

It seems that somehow something is locking the files before it even gets to the CR. What could be causing a buffer overflow when visiting these asp pages?

Comment: @Rafael Did you try to change the app pool identity to something else? Try running it under an elevated user account - just for testing.

Comment: I did change it to my local admin account which was the account I made when the computer was first setup with no difference. I also tried different app pools such as .Net 2.0 classic and normal .Net 2.0 and defaultpoolidentity.

Comment: @bkdc i'm not the person who asked, i only retagged it.

Comment: @SolidSnake4444 You could inspect the dumps with WinDbg; another thing to try is to set the app pool to No Managed Code instead of .NET (I doubt that it matters in this case). Last, but maybe most important, try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038840/instantiating-reportdocument-on-windows-7-machine-crashes-app) - seems to suggest that you version of CR is too old for Win8 or even Win7.

Comment: A year one so I guess you managed to resolve the issue. I was looking to resolve a similar issue and came across [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913384) - maybe it can help others who end up looking at this question.